# A Howler's Disposition

Tags: word, word-square, crossword-clues

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #37: Rare and Endangered 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6389)</sup>

---

I've made a 5X5 [word square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square), meaning that each word is 5 letters long and the words are the same in those positions horizontally and vertically.

**Here are the clues**:

> 1. A mixed ski-slope
> 2. Annual fluctuating celebration of defeat
> 3. A Howler’s disposition
> 4. A large father
> 5. Let me rephrase that

What words form the square?

Comment: Are these clues cryptic?

Comment: @IanMacDonald The "mixed" part of the first clue kinda is, but the rest shouldn't be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's:

> ```
> SPITE
> PURIM
> IRATE
> TITAN
> EMEND
> ```
>
> (SPITE is an anagram of 'piste')

Comment: That's it :) which #'s were the easiest/hardest for you to figure out?

Comment: I started with #1 as a guess, which led easily to #3, and the rest just kinda filled themselves in.